# Problems using ng-chart in angular 2

Tags: angular, systemjs

I've been using angular 2 for a week, I'm trying to install ng-charts, so I followed:
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts
When I do npm start, it doesn't load anything and in the browser, and the console says:
chart.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
(index):35 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-charts/ng2-charts(…)

I've been searching for hours and I think is something related with adding it to system.config.js
I added this to map:
'ng2-charts': 'node_modules/ng2-charts',
And this to packages:
'ng2-chart':{main: 'ng2-charts.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }

All packages from the documentation I've read, have an index.js, but ng-charts does not, so I thought I could use ng2-charts.js

In the instructions they say "System.js bundles can be found in bundles directory of npm package or at npm cdn" But i cant find on google what to do with that bundles... nor I can find any more detailed instructions about how to install it. For things like this I usually find everything I need already answered somewhere, I don't know what it happening today, I feel really lost :( .....

Comment: I could fix the error the not found error, the lines in the system.config.js were allright, but it still says chart.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the things I had added to map

'ng2-charts': 'node_modules/ng2-charts',

and to packages

'ng2-charts':{main: 'ng2-charts.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }

where all right

but in the doc they say to import it like this:
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';

I just import it like this:
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
I restart npm and it worked

I think in the doc theey should say: "for all newbies, dont be such a fools and import this lines to the system.config.js"

Now, what it make it worked and I could see a beautiful chart, was changing this
    src="node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js" 
For this
    src="node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.js"

when you import chart.js in the index.html

The second one does not use the line requiere()...